# Delete a child from firebase android?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

```
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
//                Toast.makeText(Map.this, marker.getPosition()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Query query = databaseReferenceMarkers.orderByChild("lat").equalTo(marker.getPosition().latitude);
                query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(Map.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Why am I not able to delete the marker?

`onChildRemoved()` --  no response.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're adding a value change listener, so `onChildRemoved()` will only be called once you remove the child, but you're removing it in the callback function.

Try it like this:

```
Query query = databaseReferenceMarkers.orderByChild("lat").equalTo(marker.getPosition().latitude);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { child.getRef().removeValue(); }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

The query returns a collection of datasnapshots where there is a match. Then you'd need to iterate over them deleting every one of them.

Comment: It deletes all the childs in the database, how to deal with that? And to see it deleted, i have to restart the activity.